# gcloud init ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, init, google-cloud-sdk

1. Google Cloud SDK installer is downloaded successfully.
2. After successful installation, it runs `gcloud init` command
3. It asked for sign-in
4. After providing signing in details, the following error occurs

   ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError):
   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443):
   Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A45426A08>:
   Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

How to handle this error?

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Check the solution here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102253/gcloud-auth-login-throwing-error-gcloud-crashed-connectionerror-httpsconnect

Answer (score 2):

I was trying `gcloud init` on a remote desktop, and received this error: `gcloud crashed (ConnectionError)`

The following solution worked for me.

I used the command `gcloud init --console-only` instead of `gcloud init`

Answer (score 2):

SSL verification fails mostly if you are behind proxy. You can disable ssl auth for gcloud client using below cmd:

```
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True
```

Comment: Is there any risk in doing this

Answer (score 0):

Google will eventually block your IP when you exceed a certain amount of requests.
You can try to create another superuser form command line may be it will resolve the issue.