# gcloud auth login throwing error: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, init, google-cloud-sdk

1. `gcloud builds submit` failed for me yesterday.
2. Then I tried `gcloud config set project`, that also failed.
3. So I thought login might have expired so tried `gcloud auth login`.

In all cases, it always throws following error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000198B0B26970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

On running diagnostics as suggested, everything seems fine.

```
>  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).
```

I have also tried with my other google account, threw same error. It was working fine 1 day before. Have tried all Stackoverflow solutions, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please run `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` as the error message suggests and post the result.

Comment: @PeteP have attached the result in post. It shows all checks passed.

Comment: Thanks for posting the update. Judging by the number of bugs posted on Google's issue tracker today I'd say it's a general problem. Check  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187143 to see what I mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is with Airtel India ISP and not Google Cloud CLI. Use a VPN, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks man! I tried with VI and it worked fine!

Comment: How did you figure this out ?

Comment: It actually worked for me by disconnecting my VPN.

Answer (score 5):

The same problem happened to me and it was a proxy issue

I followed the steps to unset the proxy

```
gcloud config unset proxy/type
gcloud config unset proxy/address
gcloud config unset proxy/port
```

reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/unset

Answer (score 2):

Disabling SSL verification as a workaround helped me

```
 gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation  True
```

Answer (score -1):

connect to a VPN
or
mac users enable Private Relay(Beta) in icloud setting