# Google cloud cli console crashed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

While trying to connect Google cloud SDK Shell, I am getting below error.

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): ('Connection aborted.', InvalidURL("URL can't contain control characters. ' http' (found at least ' ')"))

[image]

Comment: Help me with how you are trying to connect Gcloud SDK shell with either any API or Code? if you are connected with Any broadband, can you disconnect and try to connect using some VPN then this might work. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71106347/19230181) and let me know if it fixes the issues.

Comment: Are you sure there's no extra spaces anywhere like the error says? You should really comment on what you've checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): ('Connection aborted.', InvalidURL("URL can't contain control characters. ' http' (found atleast ' ')"))` is might be due to the following reasons :

1. If you are using some Python code or API client to connect then there might be some syntax error or you are giving some extra space which indicates in the error due to this you might be getting a CLI crashed error.
2. Sometimes it might get broadband issues. Can you disconnect and try to connect using some VPN or else with another broadband connection.
3. If you are using gcloud init then, Use this command gcloud init --console-only instead of gcloud init

Can you try the above solutions and let me know if this fixes your issue or else let me know if you had any further queries, happy to assist you.